# How to make and indicator show up only on 4 hour Timeframe?

Tags: pine-script

I am making moving averages that only show up on daily weely and 4-hour Timeframes. I already figured out the daily and weekly using timeframe.isdaily and timeframe.isweekly.. but the 4-hour I can't figure out.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if timeframe.period == "240"`